# how to get searched position from google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my code I have one textbox and one button. Whatever place you type into the textbox, that place has to get searched from Google maps on clicking the button. And an icon has to be shown to the searched place.
In my code I am getting the map, but I am not able to search for the location. Please help.

```
  public class MapActivity extends com.google.android.maps.MapActivity implements
    OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapView view;
Button search;
EditText location;
MapController controller;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    view = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
    location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.setOnClickListener(this);
    view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == search) {
        Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geo.getFromLocationName(location
                    .getText().toString(), 5);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (addresses.get(0)
                        .getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (addresses.get(0)
                        .getLongitude() * 1E6));

                controller.animateTo(p);
                controller.setZoom(12);
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                List<Overlay> lisOverlays = view.getOverlays();
                lisOverlays.clear();
                lisOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        MapActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                adb.setMessage("please provide proper place");
                adb.setPositiveButton("Close", null);
                adb.show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
 }
  MapOverlay.java
   public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
   {
Context context;
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas,MapView mapView,boolean shadow,long when)
{
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    GeoPoint p = null;
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),     R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return true;

}

}
```

When I compile this, I am getting an error in the line: `controller.animateTo(p);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In oncreate() instantiate the Mapcontroller as below so that you will not get an error in animateTo method.

controller= view.getController();

also GeoPioint p =null; so replace the MAp overlay class with below


MapOverlay.java

public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
GeoPoint p;
Context context;
public MyOverLay(Context context,GeoPoint p) // GeoPoint is a int. (6E) 
{ 
this.p = p; 
this.context = context;
} 
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas,MapView mapView,boolean shadow,long when)
{
    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),     R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    return true;

}
```

then in your main code pass geopoint like below it will solve your problem....

MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(getApplicationContext(),p);

Comment: ok . i can solve the error .but one more error comes is Bitmap mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts); this line.. please tell me how to solve this

Comment: i get error  MyOverLay(Context context,GeoPoint p)  in Mapoverlay.java

Comment: how to pass constructor here .. please tell me

Comment: i changed . but i get one error MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(); in Map activity. what are the parameter can pass please tell me

Comment: MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(getApplicationContext(),p);

Comment: thank u. it works but i need an icon on the searched place . this is icon code    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),     R.drawable.ic_launcher); please help me